# Laravel - Solid principles

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to ask you about SOLID principles in Laravel, in particular about the interface segregation principle.

Let's say we have application where users can send orders. But for every user we have different way to send the order. For example user one - send order via email. user two - send order via xml uploaded to ftp. In this line of thinking in php we can create interface:

```
<?php
interface ISendOrder
{
    public function sendOrder(); 
}
```

And then implement it for each specific user. But in Laravel, we have only one class User. Let's say the user have property with the user type, from which we can find the sendOrder type. What's the best way to do this in Laravel? Maybe a switch/if to find and return the correct implementation or there is a better way?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  New methods exist in 7.x that didn't exist in 5.x.  Check out PHP [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).  They were introduced as a workaround for a class that could only extend a single other class.  Hopefully that's a good start for you.

Comment: Traits doesn't help me, because I have only one class User but it has to send the order in a different way according to user type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feels like a good use-case for the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). In your example, a user can have multiple ways of sending orders. In other words, multiple strategies. It's also a good time to consider adding your Order logic to the [Service Layer](https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f).

Your question is a bit vague, admittedly, but i'll try to give an example of how I'd possibly get this done. So, let's say that your `App\User` model will implement your interface `ISendOrder`.

```
use App/Services/Order/OrderService; 
use App/Services/Order/ISendOrder;

class User extends Authenticatable implements ISendOrder 
{
    protected $orderStrategies = [
        'standard' => App/Services/Order/Strategies/StandardStrategy::class, 
        'vip' => App/Services/Order/Strategies/VipStrategy::class
    ];

    public function sendOrder(Order $order, OrderService $service)
    {
        $service->setStrategy($this->orderStrategies[$this->type]); 

        return $service->sendOrder($this, $order); 
    }
}
```

A very minimal example of your `OrderService` would look like this:

```
class OrderService 
{
    protected $strategy; 

    public function setStrategy(OrderStrategy $strategy)
    {
        $this->strategy = $strategy; 
    }

    public function sendOrder(ISendOrder $user, Order $order)
    {
        // logic to send order 
        // $this->strategy holds the strategy to be used
    }
}
```

This step is purely optional, but I would probably encapsulate the order sending logic in a trait. Your model will look a lot cleaner. Also, you can easily add this logic to any other `models` that could possibly sends order in the future.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements ISendOrder 
{
    use InteractsWithOrder;
}
```

Your trait would look like this:

```
trait InteractsWithOrder
{
    protected $orderStrategies = [
        'standard' => App/Services/Order/Strategies/StandardStrategy::class, 
        'vip' => App/Services/Order/Strategies/VipStrategy::class 
    ];

    public function sendOrder(Order $order, OrderService $service)
    {
        $strategy = new $this->orderStrategies[$this->type]; 

        $service->setStrategy($strategy); 

        return $service->sendOrder($this, $order); 
    }
}
```

This is a very minimal example to illustrate how you could *possibly* get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with subjective questions like "what's the best way...", this site is really for specifics.  But there are some things about your question that may help.

**S**ingle Responsability: A class should have only one reason to change.  If you encounter more than one, refactor it into separate classes.  i.e. Don't fuse the concepts of "User" and "Message Driver" in the same class.

**O**pen Closed: A class should be open to extending or overriding with child classes, but closed to modifying the input or output of existing methods in an of itself.  i.e. Don't pull the rug out from something that might already be using that class.  Feature Tests are a good way to ensure that refactors don't accidentally do this.

**L**iskov Substitution: Sibling Classes should be interchangeable.  You speak of having different kinds of transmission drivers.  Email vs. FTP.  Your EmailDriver and FtpDriver classes should both implement an interface defining a `send()` method.  So then anything that uses one should also be able to cope with the other.  Your Adapter class, that consumes both the `User` to be communicated with and the `Driver` defining the mechanism of communication then doesn't have to care about the specifics.

**I**nterface Segregation: In a nutshell, keep your Interfaces slim.  A class can always implement more than one if it wants to.  If a single Interface is asking the object to support too much, more than may actually be necessary, it can lead into needless complexity.

**D**ependency Inversion: This kind of goes hand-in-hand with Liskov Substitution.  High-level classes should depend on Interfaces rather than Concrete classes, to make it easier to swap out components when needed with minimal refactoring.

Laravel's [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container) does a lot of this.  [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers) bind Concrete classes to Abstractions.  Typically those abstractions are string interface names, but they can actually be any string.  This is partly how [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) work.

Laravel's way of instantiating new objects should always be by [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  Either by [Type Hinting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#automatic-injection) where applicable, or using the [`app()` Helper Function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-app).

What you're doing when you ask Laravel to instantiate an object in this way, is giving the Container the opportunity to swap out the class you're asking for with the class defined in the Provider.

Getting back to your specific issue though, when it comes to instructing your code which transmission driver to leverage for whom, I cant say for sure without more information, and this is just an opinion, but you might want to see if the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) fits your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this hoping it could clear someone's concept's fully about interface segregation.

I think, @mozammil gives you the best answer for Laravel specific case.

But if you have the clear concept about this interface segregation, then it's as simple to utilize in any programming case - `Java`, `PHP`, `C#`, `Python` or in any programming languages.

**Interface Segregation:**

Client/User should not depend upon the interfaces that they can not use, rather than segregate the interfaces to several one.

Like Check everything goes correct if we do this.

```php
interface Payment{
  public function initiatePayments();
  public function getPayment();
}

public class BankPayment implements Payment{
  public function initiatePayments(){
    // Do initialization
  }

  public function getPayment(){
    // Make Payments Stuff
  }
}
```

`BankPayment` class use two functions which are relevant to it and necessary. But, if any new things arrived. Like needed to add loan calculation and check.

```php
interface Payment{
  public function initiatePayments();
  public function getPayment();

  public function getLoanHistory();
  public function printLoanPayments();
}

public class LoanPayment implements Payment{
  public function initiatePayments(){
    // Do initialization
  }

  public function getPayment(){
    // Make Payments Stuff
  }
  
  // Ok for this class
  public function getLoanHistory(){
    
  }

  // Ok for this class
  public function printLoanPayments(){

  }
}

public class BankPayment implements Payment{
  public function initiatePayments(){
    // Do initialization
  }

  public function getPayment(){
    // Make Payments Stuff
  }

  // Not Necessary for this class but have to implement
  public function getLoanHistory(){
    
  }

  // Not Necessary this class but have to implement
  public function printLoanPayments(){

  }
}
```

Look at this for `LoanPayment` class everything was ok, but for `BankPayment` class the new two functions are unnecessary and should have been segregated in another interface.

That's the Interface Segregation Principle in SOLID.

**To get full concept and real-life implementation about SOLID principles every concept with code in PHP, you can check this out** - https://devsenv.com/tutorials/solid-principle-in-depth-with-practical-example